# Java - need help to construct a regex patternn

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I have a string where im trying to extract a specic section of words and was hoping if someone could help me with a safe way of parsing the string to get just this sections. The string is formated as such...

```
_____ _____ replied to _____ _____ about the **THIS IS THE PART I NEED TO GET** topic in the _____ forum.
```

Wherever there is a blank than it is possible that any word could be there, also the part that i need to get could be of any length.

Comment: What do you mean by verbose?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean. A sample input and expected output would help

Comment: by verbose I ment a safe way of parsing it where I would not accidently get the wrong parts of the string.

Comment: I havent tried anything yet, i know i could get the a substring from the word "the" to the word "topic" but donno how to compensate if the string i am trying to get contains the word "topic" in it.

Comment: @user1103205 in the worst case, both the `topic` and the `forum` name contain `"topic in the"`, in which case there is no way to tell which part you actually want

Comment: you can use the [lastIndex()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.String)) method to find the last _topic_ in your String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a regex that matches what you posted and extracts the content that you put in the `**` in a group.

```
^.*replied to.*about the (.*) topic in the .* forum\.$
```

You can test it [here](http://rubular.com/r/iTEsnsnapG).

The *non-greedy* version looks like

```
^.*?replied to.*?about the (.*) topic in the .* forum\.$
```

You can test it [here](http://rubular.com/r/jvATunsM1H).

These are the **RAW** regular expressions, for Java you need to escape the `\` with `\\`.

*unlike most regex questions here this one is actually a good fit for a regular expression*

Comment: I think I'd make the first to repetitions ungreedy, so as to include as much as possible in the topic name, should it contain `replied to` or `about the`.

Comment: @m.buettner feel free to edit my answer if you would like to improve it.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I just wanted to make a suggestion for you to adapt or not... you might as well have good reasons not to use an ungreedy quantifier ;). It's not like it's a mistake based on the question.

Comment: Since im using this in java i am getting an error "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )" when pasting the regex expression in the Pattern.compile() method

Comment: @user1103205 escape the \, `"^.*replied to.*about the (.*) topic in the .* forum\\.$"` should work in java source code.

Comment: those are **RAW** regexes you have to escape all the \. So the `\\.` at the end in Java has to be `\\.`